# how to subtract two Equations and changes the symbol?

Tags: equations

when we try to subtract algebraic equations we need to change the sign how to type this and produce the result in latex[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the entire structure inside an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% Remove column separation
  \begin{array}{ c r c r c r }
    - & 15 x^2 y & {}+{} &  3x & {}-{} & 15 \\
    + & 10 x^2 y & {}+{} & 10x & {}-{} &  7 \\
    - &          & {}-{} &     & {}+{} &    \\
    \hline
    - & 25 x^2 y & {}-{} &  7x & {}-{} &  8
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The space around the operators are corrected (from unary to binary) using `{}<op>{}`.

Nice one!